# Angular access html content via .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get access input field [newUser] value in button click action [onAddUser()] in .ts file.

```
<input type="text" 
        ng-model="newUser"
        style="text-align:center"/>
<button (click)="onAddUser()" >Add User</button>
```

Comment: The code is mixing AngularJS directives with Angular 2+ directives. `ng-model` is an AngularJS directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Angular (not AngularJS 1.x) then you need to change the NgModel syntax:

In HTML (template):

```
<input type="text" 
         [(ngModel)]="newUser"
         style="text-align:center"/>
<button (click)="onAddUser()" >Add User</button>
```

In TS file:

```
export class YourComponent {
  newUser: string;

  onAddUser(){
    alert(this.newUser); //get the input value
  }
}
```

Also, remember to import the FormsModule:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```